# PHP7 Not connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2012

I have been searching for an answer for last 3 days before posting.

I have installed SQL Server 2012 and, Apache24, PHP7.0 
The Apache started fine, PHP7 Started fine 
I can browse localhost/info.php and it shows perfect 
Installed ODBC 
Installed the SQL extensions drivers 
Configured PHP.ini and apache conf file

SQL services started through SQL configuration manager 
also allowed in the network configuration the TCP\IP and named pipes

I can't login to the SQL server using Microsoft SQL server manager

So all seems to be fine but every time I try to do a simple PHP code to connect my PHP to the SQL server I get the below error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it. in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php on line 13 Could not connect

Have disabled the firewall also and even added a rule with few ports 
I am running on windows 10 Enterprise

Also when I change the server name to WALEED\SQLEXPRESS I get the below

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php on line
>   13

Tried to search in the SQL server log but couldn't find any errors

All extensions for my PHP are working fine on info.php

Index file :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'admin';
$dbpass = 'admin2017';
$db     = 'sunto';    

$conn  = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);

if(! $conn){
  die('Could not connect') ;
}

echo 'Successfully Connected';    

$sql = 'Connected Successfully';
  $retvalue = mysqli_query($sql);

  if(! $retvalue){
    die('Cannot connect to SQL: ');
  }

echo 'DataBase test_db13 has successfully created';    
mysqli_close($conn);    
?>
```

Comment: *"I can't login to the sql server using microsoft sql server manager

So all seems to be fine"* - do you mean *can* ?

Comment: Your problem has to do with the installation.Take a look at this site: https://www.saotn.org/install-microsoft-sql-server-driver-php

Comment: Jose Marques, The article is a Great help thank you Boss :)

Comment: But what is strange when i Try to connect with  sqlsrv_connect( "localhost", $connectionInfo );    it is fine connected but when i try to connect using mysqli. it shows error >> how to add mysqli to the firewall maybe !

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` is for MySQL not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you said:

> what is strange when i Try to connect with sqlsrv_connect(
>   "localhost", $connectionInfo ); it is fine connected but when i try to
>   connect using mysqli. it shows error

There's nothing strange about that. The clue's right there in the name of the method you're using:

**mysql**i_connect()

That code library is for connecting to **MySQL** databases only.

You need to use the **sqlsrv_** library instead if you want to connect to **SQL Server**. They're completely different database platforms, with completely different PHP libraries to use for working with them. As you saw yourself, it works when you use `sqlsrv_connect`.

I'm not really sure why you then tried to use `mysqli` after that, or why you expected that to be successful.